# error on react app building: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

Tags: reactjs, build, github-pages, vite, react-typescript

I have already looked through many articles related to the current error and can't find the solution.
I got error[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXwf9.png), but **after page refresh the application has been loaded**.
Guess current error caused **problem with app building on [Github]**(https://serhii-yunnikov.github.io/ip-address-tracker/)

main.tsx:

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <App />
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://serhii-yunnikov.github.io/ip-address-tracker/",
  "name": "ip-address-tracker",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm-run-build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.32.6",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.32.6",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "esri-leaflet-geocoder": "^3.1.4",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "sass": "^1.64.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "padiv": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>IP ADDRESS TRACKER</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to clean the cache and install latest dependencies typescript, vite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going down a rabbit hole for an hour thinking it had something to do with sass, it turns out it's just a [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/serhii-yunnikov/ip-address-tracker/blob/main/tsconfig.json#L24) configuration error.

Change `padiv`:

```json
"references": [{ "padiv": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
```

to `path`:

```json
"references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
```

---

On a separate note, your .env file should be added to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: how did you do this?) GPT could not) that was caused by shift+cmnd+f in vscode) 
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Chat gippity is great and all, but it can’t debug a project. What I did was break down the project into smaller and smaller parts until I narrowed down what was causing the error. In this case, I created a new vite reactjs project and migrated over the existing project in pieces until the error popped up. Debugging is just as important as writing code!